# questions about oculus quest 2 development or capabilities :

Tags: oculus

I have 3 questions about oculus quest 2 development or capabilities :

1- first of all is it possible to create an app in oculus quest in order to have shortcuts in the helmet to run specific applications directly after launching the helmet (without going into the main menu, search for the app, ...) ? The purpose of theses quick links is also to switch from App A to App B easily (without to much or complex interactions)

2- Is it possible to avoid the position setup when the quest helmet launches (confirm floor level, or define play area) ? I dont know why but when I restart the helmet, even if the position has not changed beetween my previous experience, I need to redefine floor level and stationary boundary every time.

3- Is it possible to run the cast functionnality automaticaly when we start the helmet ?

Thanks for your help.

Joris

Answer (score 0):

1 - You can launch other apps using deep linking.
https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unity/ps-deep-linking/

2 - You are seeing guardian setup because it doesn't recognize the area as being the same. This may be due to lighting changes or things getting moved around.

3 - This is not possible to my knowledge. Possibly limited for privacy reasons.